# how can I toggle between three different variables in an array?

Tags: javascript

How can a 3 conditions toggle go back and forth? Thanks
Basically I have a drop down menu in which It has three different names that   each of them has their own particular explanation.

```
    $scope.dropDownMenu = ["East","West","Central"];
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.dropDownMenu[0];
    if($scope.selectedItem === "East") 
        $scope.selectedItem  = $scope.dropDownMenu[1];
    and so on.....
```

It is easy to toggle between to variable in an array but three? I dont really know how.

1. 1.the next info after East can be West or Central, and not just west
2. the next info after West can be East or Central, and not just
   Central
3. the next info after Central can be East or West, and not just East

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of the index.

```
function toggle() {
  var nextIndex = $scope.currentIndex + 1;

  if (nextIndex >= $scope.dropDownMenu.length) {
    nextIndex = 0;
  }

  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.dropDownMenu[nextIndex];
  $scope.currentIndex = nextIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Kyle